# InvalidCastException on Result of Indexing Into an ArrayList

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have an ArrayList filled with a bunch of Points and I want to loop over them, so I use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentClicks.Count; i++)
{
    if (i > 0) // Skip the first click
    {
        clickPos = currentClicks[i];
        prevPos = currentClicks[i - 1];
    }
}
```

and I get this error on the `clickPos` and `prevPos` lines:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Drawing.Point'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Why is this? I have `clickPos` and `prevPos` defined as so:

```
private System.Drawing.Point clickPos;
private System.Drawing.Point prevPos;
```

## Edit

When I comment out the `clickPos` and `prevPos` lines and add

```
MessageBox.Show(currentClicks[i].GetType().ToString());
```

the message box says `System.Drawing.Point`

Comment: Where do you define currentClicks?

Comment: Form1.Designer.cs; The code that gives the error is in Form1.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the generic `List<Point>` instead of an `ArrayList`.

If you insist on using an ArrayList, you'll need to cast the objects to a `Point` when you retrieve them:

```
clickPos = (Point)currentClicks[i];
```

Comment: Dear God, yes; use a List<Point>. +1. The only reason ever to use an ArrayList in VS2008 is for compatibility with the Settings file.  Also, once you have the List<Point>, iterate over it with a foreach loop rather than a for loop.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < currentClicks.Count; i++)
{
    clickPos = (System.Drawing.Point)currentClicks[i];
    prevPos = (System.Drawing.Point)currentClicks[i - 1];
}
```

A better solution could be using a generic list, a `List<Point>`, then you wouldn't need the cast at all.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayLists` are not strongly typed.  They are basically an `IList` of `object`.

Because of this, you need to cast your references to the arraylist elements to the type that you know they are.

```
    clickPos = (Point)currentClicks[i];
    prevPos = (Point)currentClicks[i - 1];
```

I would strongly recommend using a `List<Point>` rather than an `ArrayList`.  This will give you a strongly typed list of Points and remove the requirement for having to cast your references.

A generic `List<T>` also offers the exact same functionality as an `ArrayList`, but generally with better performance.  [**From the documentation:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> **Performance Considerations**
>
> In deciding whether to use the List or
>   ArrayList class, both of which have
>   similar functionality, remember that
>   the List class performs better in most
>   cases and is type safe. If a reference
>   type is used for type T of the List
>   class, the behavior of the two classes
>   is identical.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you just start with 1?

```
for (int i = 1; i < currentClicks.Count; i++) 
{ 
         clickPos = (System.Drawing.Point)currentClicks[i];
        prevPos = (System.Drawing.Point)currentClicks[i - 1];
}
```

Comment: =p Good idea. I'm from a Ruby background, so I'm not used to all of these for loops

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your edit: *you* know the ArrayList holds points, and the *runtime* knows the ArrayList holds points (hence the `.GetType()` result), but the *compiler* does not know the arraylist holds points.  You need a cast there to satisfy the compiler.

But really, the only correct way to fix this is to change it to a generic `List<Point>`.

Answer (score 0):

Nick's code will work, or you could try using:

`ArrayList<System.Drawing.Point>`

The ArrayList implements IEnumerable, which means it always hands back System.Object. `ArrayList<T>` implements IEnumerable and will always hand back a T.

Comment: ArrayList is non-generic. Did you mean to suggest `List<Point>`? That would return a strongly typed `T` without the need to cast the object.

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` contains references to objects, and you're attempting to implicitly cast those objects to Points.  You can either explicitly cast, as Nick shows, or use a generic `List<T>` instead, which is what I would recommend:

```
List<Point> currentClicks = new List<Point>();
// add your points
```

Using a generic List (added to .NET in 2.0, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)) allows you to work with objects in a much more type-safe manner, without runtime casts.  If you're working with .NET 2.0 or greater, you should never use `ArrayList`, `Hashtable`, or any of the other non-generic constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are stuck on .NET 1.1 or have no control over the creation of the list, you would be better off with `List<Point>`

the ArrayList requires that you use explict casts to get at the members unless you want to use them simply as object, so you need this

```
clickPos = (Point)currentClicks[i];
prevPos = (Point)currentClicks[i - 1];
```